# Tablesorter with dynamic columns number

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

I'm working with Tablesorter and I have the following problem. 
I have a table, which has a variable number of columns (depending the kind of element selected, this table has 20 or 25 columns). 
The common columns are sorted perfectly, but when I use if-statements in my php code to select if a column is created or not, the tablesorter doesn't work anymore. Just to remark, without this conditions, everything works ok.

Any idea why can this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give some code to see what exactly you are trying to do? Its hard to get a good picture of where the problem lies this way..

Comment: I don't know how wxactly post my code...coz it's a large php code where I create a table with 25 columns depending of many conditions...The code size is really big!

Comment: Without code, we can not help you. It's like, if I ask, "hey guys, my code is worked, but now it isn't. What is the problem?" Use jsfiddle.

Comment: What you can do, is just post the most relevant code so that we get an idea of what you are doing, maybe with a few comments here and there.